# JavasScript validation works with two fields. However want to do or one one field

Tags: javascript, html

ideally id like to validate both phone number and email from the one 'search field'. However it only works individually. I think i'm doing it rite by using the JS || operator for or.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <form method="POST"  action="/">
        <dl style="display:inline-block">
        <input type="text" id="search">
        </dl>   
        <button id="searchbutton" style="display:inline-block" type="submit"  class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" onclick="doValidate()" >Search</button>

    </form>
</div>  
<script>
function validateEmail(email) { //Validates the email address
  var emailRegex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return emailRegex.test(email);
}

function validatePhone(phone) { //Validates the phone number
  var phoneRegex = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/; // Change this regex based on requirement
  return phoneRegex.test(phone);
}

function doValidate() {
  if (!validateEmail(document.getElementById('search').value) || !validatePhone(document.getElementById('search').value)) {
    alert("Invalid Email(abc@mail.com) or Phone 111-111-1111");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem with or is one of them is false, it will go into it. `If (THIS IS FALSE OR THAT IS FALSE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you missed return on your click handler so it will always submit. Second your check is always going to go into the alert because one of the checks is always going to be false. So you need to change your logic to check one to see if it is false and then check the other.

so the line below says if email is true, than it is true, if not it will check the phone number

```
var isValid = validateEmail(document.getElementById('search').value) || validatePhone(document.getElementById('search').value)
```

```js
function validateEmail(email) { //Validates the email address
  var emailRegex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return emailRegex.test(email);
}

function validatePhone(phone) { //Validates the phone number
  var phoneRegex = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/; // Change this regex based on requirement
  return phoneRegex.test(phone);
}

function doValidate() {
  var isValid = validateEmail(document.getElementById('search').value) || validatePhone(document.getElementById('search').value)
  if (!isValid) {
    alert("Invalid Email(abc@mail.com) or Phone 111-111-1111");
    return false;
  }
  return true
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <form method="POST" action="/" onsubmit="return doValidate()">
    <dl style="display:inline-block">
      <input type="text" id="search">
    </dl>
    <button id="searchbutton" style="display:inline-block" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" >Search</button>

  </form>
</div>
```